# Create a class from string

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this interface:

```
export interface Base {
  name: string;
}
```

And a class:

```
export class SampleClass implements Base {
  name = 'Testing';
  constructor() {}
}
```

Then in another class, I tried to create the class 'SampleClass' from string:

```
const sampleClass = Object.create(window['SampleClass'].prototype);
```

But got an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Then I tried this other way:

```
const secClass: any = new (<any>window)['SampleClass']();
```

And got this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: window.SampleClass is not a constructor
```

How to correctly create an object from string?

Comment: You can do const [sampleClass = Object.create(SampleClass)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). Where [window](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp) and prototype come in is what is confusing me in your code. I understand [prototype](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) but not as you have written it.

Comment: Object.create('SampleClass') is not possible.  the create method is asking for object.

Comment: actually my goal is to create the object using string.  so i don't understand your answer.

Comment: I tried replicating this in typescript playground. It appears object.create() needs an instance already to work for your scenario. So if you did i = new SampleClass(); alert(i.name) - that would work - if you did o = object.create(SampleClass) then do alert(o.name) - you get undefined. However if you do o = object.create(i); alert(o.name) - then you get 'Testing' again. Not sure if that helps you... (I dropped exports to make it work. But for sure it would work with relevant imports elsewhere)

Comment: ok. maybe i need to rephrase the question.  i have an array of strings ['MyClass1', 'MyClass2', 'MyClass3', 'MyClass4',...].  Given only that information, I want to create an object for each of the string.  I mean your answer seems to tell me I need to directly instantiate the class.  that's not what i want.  i want to create a class from string.

Comment: why are you trying to create it over the window object itself? And would  this [].prototype be redefining array?

Comment: i'm trying to solve my issue.  i found these codes while searching, thus i tried these codes.

Comment: i think this has become too lengthy discussion.  i think you don't know the answer to my question.  i also don't know how to answer my question.  so we're just going round in circles.